# What can cause a capacitor/supercapacitor to not charge up to source?

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I'm doing a project that involves charging an experimental supercapacitor with a 9 volt battery and then turning a red LED on with it.

Now, I've asked around what determines to what voltage a capacitor will charge and what they've told me is that the voltage rating is for safety based on dielectric thickness, but the capacitor will theoretically charge up to however many volts the source has.

But when I try to charge the supercap with the 9V all it ever gets to is 1.1 V, and never gets any higher.

All I can think of is that it might be voltage drop since it's a crudely made carbon supercapacitor with high resistance (measured at around 1500 Ohms). However when I try with a brand new 9V battery (measures at 9.5 V) and an old 9V battery (down to 6.5 V) it always gets to 1.1 V all the same and stops there.

Batteries are standard 9V 340 mAh, supercap capacitance measures at 1.4 mF. What am I missing here? Would thicker dielectric work?

Comment: Measure the charging current when it stops increasing in voltage and see what is happening. Probably it's still taking current but it's leaking across the dielectric.

Comment: What's the rated voltage of the supercapacitor? Typical supercapacitors will break down at just a few volts, and 9 V is a very high rating for one. Whoever said you can overcharge a capacitor was wrong--or at least right but not telling the whole story. Or you were misunderstanding what they were saying. The voltage rating of a capacitor should be treated as a "DO NOT CHARGE BEYOND THIS VOLTAGE" sign.

Comment: New account so I'll reply to both of you here. Apparently there's still 6.6 V in the circuit when the cap tops at 1.1 V. I made the cap myself so voltage rating is unknown, I do agree 9V is a lot, I was putting it through resistors at first but took them out thinking it could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: @user18038282 Sounds to me like you've broken your capacitor. Resistors or no resistors you've still hooked it up to too high a voltage.

Comment: @Hearth I can make a new one, it's just a bit of activated carbon on nickel foam straps as electrodes and a plastic layer as dielectric. I made a second one in trying to solve this and the same thing happened to it (dielectric was the same). I'm thinking of trying either thicker dielectric or a couple 1.5V as source (or both) for the next one. Could that work?

Comment: I would try limiting your charge voltage to about 1 V. Having 1.1 V across the capacitor when it's fully charged suggests that the breakdown is around 1.1 V.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "supercapacitor," but "plastic layer as dielectric" does not describe the kind of capacitor that other comments here are talking about. Did you maybe mean, porous plastic _membrane?_ The dielectric in a supercapacitor (and also, in an ordinary electrolytic capacitor) is a thin film on one of the electrodes that is formed by chemical action of the electrolyte on the electrode. It is the extreme thinness of that film that causes such capacitors to have such low voltage ratings.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It's a polypropylene membrane, I saw it in other lab and otherwise non-commercial supercaps. It may very well not be porous enough. Maybe paper of some kind?